# I have multiple, identical classes, is there a way I can edit the data of each separately?

Tags: python, class

SO to begin, I have this class Orc initialized here :

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, health, defence, strength, name, currenthealth, image):
        Enemy.health = health
        Enemy.defence = defence
        Enemy.strength = strength
        Enemy.name = name
        Enemy.currenthealth = currenthealth
        Enemy.image = image

class Orc(Enemy):
    def __init__(self, health, defence, strength, name, currenthealth, image):
        super().__init__(health, defence, strength, name, currenthealth, image)

orc = (Orc(10, 5, 5, "Orc", 10, Orcimg))
enemies.append(orc)
```

And I subsequently add it to list displayset, where I do this up to 4 times (for 4 separate enemies)

```
def randomencounter(enemies) :
    numofopps = random.randint(1, 4)
    enemyset = []
    displayset =  []
    x = 0
    pygame.display.update()
    while x != (numofopps):
        enemyset.append(str((enemies[0].name)))
        displayset.append(enemies[0])
        time.sleep(0.5)
        x = x + 1
    return displayset, enemyset, numofopps
```

And when I try to edit them seperately...

I found that, while one was removed, the other data also changed[Data has been (in)correctly affected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QzA0.png)

I subtract 6 from the "health" (while it didn't actually calculate the "death" properly that is fixable) from the 2nd target, the other 2 remaining ones also had their "health" deducted by 6.

My expectation was that I could edit the items in the list as classes separately, without creating multiple different variables with the class data inherited. Is there any way that this is still the case?

targeting code is here for anyone interested (it's still bulky even though I have only included the code for 3 enemies present, and I apologise accordingly; I also apologise for it being slightly unwieldly to look at) :

```
    pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if len(displayset) == 3:
                if (((displayset[2].image).get_rect(center=((1320 + (0.5 * Imagex[2])),(300+ (0.5 * Imagey[2]))))).collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) == True) and Imagex[2] != None:
                    print("3")
                    Leftbutton, NUL2, NUL3 = pygame.mouse.get_pressed(num_buttons=3)
                    if Leftbutton == True:
                        return displayset[2], 2
                        GGG = 1
                elif ((((displayset[1].image).get_rect(center=((920 + (0.5 * Imagex[1])),(300+ (0.5 * Imagey[1]))))).collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())) == True) and Imagex[1] != None:
                    print("2")
                    Leftbutton, NUL2, NUL3 = pygame.mouse.get_pressed(num_buttons=3)
                    if Leftbutton == True:
                        return displayset[1], 1
                        GGG = 1
                elif ((displayset[0].image).get_rect(center=((520 + (0.5 * Imagex[0])),(300+ (0.5 * Imagey[0])))).collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) == True) and Imagex[0] != None:
                    print("1")
                    Leftbutton, NUL2, NUL3 = pygame.mouse.get_pressed(num_buttons=3)
                    if Leftbutton == True:
                        return displayset[0], 0
                        GGG = 1
```

[The code for determining the "death" (yeah I have the wrong sign I know")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eUlm.png)

I have tried using the list index to edit separate items but that seems to not be working.
I appreciate you taking the time to read this, my amateur brain feels partly fried...
alongside apologising for probably structuring this incorrectly

Comment: Typo: you're using `Enemy` instead of `self` in `Enemy.__init__`. You're setting attributes on the class, not on the instance `self`

Comment: As a side note, `Enemy` would be a good candidate for a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)

Comment: "I have multiple, identical classes" - you really shouldn't. You don't need multiple identical classes for this; multiple instances of a single class do the job, as long as you fix the class attribute bug.

Comment: Is that not the same thing? I just need multiple of X class that I can edit separately.

Comment: And if not, how does one go about the multiple instances? I am still quite new to this.

Comment: In the `randomencounter()` function, I see that you are always appending the _same_ enemy `enemies[0]` to the list.  Surely that's a mistake?

Comment: I think that might be the issue, it would mean I would need to create my set of enemy classes some other way, I just do not know how

Comment: @DDA Maybe you could use `enemies[x]`.

Comment: I workaround I have thought of Is to use a 2 dimensional list, that holds 4 separate instances of the specific enemy class, I will have to see if that works...

Answer (score 2):

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, health, defence, strength, name, currenthealth, image):
        Enemy.health = health
        ...
```

You want to use `self.health` here, not `Enemy.health`.

`self` refers to *this individual class instance*, but `Enemy` refers to *the entire class*.  Which explains your problem about duplicate data.

```
class Orc(Enemy):
    def __init__(self, health, defence, strength, name, currenthealth, image):
        super().__init__(health, defence, strength, name, currenthealth, image)
```

You've redefined `__init__` here to do *the exact same thing* that the parent `__init__` does.  Might as well not define `__init__` in the child class at all, and just let it inherit that method from the parent class.

Comment: I tried this and It unfortunately did not solve the problem, all the classes still get edited, did I miss something?

Comment: @DDA I can't answer that without seeing the full new code.

Comment: Here you are https://imgur.com/a/N8pFEZS

Comment: @DDA Okay, that part looks fine, but you say there is still a problem somewhere.  We can't find the problem unless you show the full code, and show us some output that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: These are the parts that deal with the editing of the data, if that is what you needhttps://imgur.com/a/ghQD0NE

Comment: @DDA What I need is the FULL code, so I can run this myself and (hopefully) see the same results that you see, so I can understand what is actually happening.  Giving me bits and pieces of the code is not enough.

Comment: @DDA Also, did you see my new comment on the question above?